# Angular Universal app can't make post requests to my Heroku node API

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

My website is a SPA built with Angular, but it uses SSR with Angular Universal to provide crawlable and social media sharing content.

All GET requests in my server are handled by Universal like this:

```
app.engine(


'html',
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: ServerAppModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [provider]
  })
)

app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('views', __dirname)

app.use('/', express.static('./dist', {index: false}))
app.use('/', expressStaticGzip('./dist', {
  enableBrotli: true
}))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('./dist/index', {
        req: req,
        res: res
    })
})
```

and my pages contents are provided by Angular Services POST requests built with the same queryParams of the requested url.

One example:

If the user visits the url https://mywebsite.com/products?page=1&itemsPerPage=12 (GET request by default), the Angular Universal app and the Angular Router dynamically build my page template and the products list is provided by a Service that triggers a POST request to this URL: https://mywebsite.com/request-products with the following params in body:

```
{
    page: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 12
}
```

Then the Universal App builds the template with some *ngFor directives to populate it before serving it to the client.

This approach makes all my pages visible to webcrawlers and I also get the benefits of a Single Page Application.

When I'm testing my app, I build my Angular app, both Browser and Server builds, and set my environment like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:7070/'
}
```

and serves my app in localhost, it works perfectly, without errors. My POST requests, like mentioned before, are all handled perfectly. But when I try to set my apiUrl to 'https://mywebsite.com/' and serve my app also in localhost, to access directly my API hosted in Heroku, I just can't access my POST routes.

My node express server app in Heroku is configured to accept requests from other domains, I can access it normally in my localhost server, but when I try to access it through my Angular Universal server build, it just won't work.

I know that I have to use absolute URLS in my Universal Apps, and I'm doing it already, but it's not working.

Does anyone know what I have to do to access external APIs in my Angular Universal Apps via https?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, and it's something really simple.

It turns out that I must use 'www' in my absolute url, like this:

'https://www.mywebsite.com/'

Now everything works perfectly, both from my localhost and my heroku servers.

Thanks to everyone that took some time to read my question!